# How do i search and replace the entire cell content by a string in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I have some cases to replace the following string with another string `TES1` if the string has **_M1** in it. Where ever _M1 is there I have to replace the whole cell content with TES1. similarly, I need to change _M2 to TES2, _M3 to TES3. I am using a google sheet or excel in mac. Can you please help me?

```
SC5_LO_007_M1
SC5_LO_007_M2
SC5_LO_104_M1
SC5_LO_104_M1
SC5_LO_104_M3
SC5_LO_001_M1
SC5_LO_008_M2
SC5_LO_008_M3
SC5_LO_009_M1
```

Comment: Please refer to this article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/find-or-replace-text-and-numbers-on-a-worksheet-0e304ca5-ecef-4808-b90f-fdb42f892e90

Answer (score 1):

With data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
=if(isnumber(find("_M1",A1)),"TES1",A1)
```

and copy downwards.

[image]

Comment: it is really helpful. thank you. But I have another issue, similarly, I need to change _M2 to TES2, _M3 to TES3.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Sheets, you can use Regular Expressions.

So:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1,"^.*_M(\d+)$","TES$1")
```

The regex checks to see if the string ends with `_Mn` where `n` is one or more digits.

It then replaces the entire string with that digit prepended by `TES`.

[image]

In MAC Excel you can try:

```
=IFERROR("TES" & MID(A1,FIND("_M",A1)+2,99),A1)
```

If your `_Mn` string may not always be at the end, please clarify your question.